# Creating multiple Wordpress category divs

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site which uses images replacing category text. It is set up to have a post div (padding: 20% 0; for consistent responsive height ) Then has a div positioned absolute, vert/horiz centred overtop this div.

html

```
<div class="indx-img" style="background-image:url('...');">

        <?php 
        $testStyle = "";

        if(has_category( 'update' ) || has_category( 'uncategorized' )) {
            $testStyle = "style=\"background-image:url('".get_bloginfo('template_directory')."/img/logo.png')\"";
        } elseif(has_category( 'event' )) {
            $testStyle = "style=\"background-image:url('".get_bloginfo('template_directory')."/img/logo.png')\"";
        }
        ?>

            <div class="test" <?php echo $testStyle; ?>></div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.indx-img {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20% 0;
}

.test {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -5em;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
}
```

This put's a background image for test. The problem with this is if a post has more than one category on it, only one will show.

Ideally I want a div created in 'test' for each category applied to the post with the category-image, aligned next to each other.

Comment: One question: Why are your statements in `if` and `elseif` identical?? If that's how they're supposed to be then I see no point in using `if-elseif`. A single `if` should suffice.

Comment: they will change, right now they are like that just to make sure it works, there will be more than 2 statements in the end, and each will have a different pic

Answer (score 0):

By your code, I guess that your HTML div code is running for single post. and as you are checking for single category with has_category, it will give you on category only.

For getting all category of any post, you would required `wp_get_post_categories` function.

```
$post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );
$cats = array();

foreach($post_categories as $c){
    $cat = get_category( $c );
    $cats[] = array( 'name' => $cat->name, 'slug' => $cat->slug );
}
```

In this way, you can get category list and can put apply style code accordingly. see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories more details of `wp_get_post_categories` usage.

Comment: sweet, that seems like the right track, are there any other sources with examples that you have come across that explains it further?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org this is itself wordpress community, you can get all functions details with parameter and usage of it

Rather than its original definition of each function, you can always use it with your code as per your requirement, and as all have different requirements, its not easily possible that you get exact code how you want it